# DevExpress ASPxPivotGrid Custom Summary Calculation for unbound fields

Tags: controls, devexpress

I am evaluating ASPxPivotGrid.  So far, it's perfect for what I need to do and I'm ready to buy it, but I have one hiccup that I don't understand how to implement.  I need to do calculations on fields.  That part I think I get, I create an unbound field and enter the formula I want.  That works fine.  The problem is the summary data defaults to Sum, which I don't want since it's a percentage calculation.  For instance:

Bound Fields: Sales, Profit

Unbound Field Calculation = Profit / Sales * 100

This is to calculate the Profit Margin %.

Like I said it works when the pivot displays raw data, but once it summarizes, I want it to calculate the Profit Margin % on the summarized totals of Profit and Sales.  So, something like this:

Summary Profit Margin % = Sum(Profit) / Sum(Sales) * 100

I have searched on their forum and see what seems like related material on the subject, but I don't know enough about the product to make sense of what I should be doing either in the property settings or in code.  There does not seem to be a clear tutorial or explanation of this anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your task properly, you want to calculate expressions based on data shown in PivotGrid cells.  If so, this behavior is controlled by the [OptionsData.DataFieldUnboundExpressionMode](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#CoreLibraries/DevExpressXtraPivotGridPivotGridOptionsData_DataFieldUnboundExpressionModetopic) option.  In your case, you should set this property to the DataFieldUnboundExpressionMode.UseSummaryValues value.  We have shown this functionality in Winforms and WPF UnboundExpression demo. There is a drawback though.  Expression's total value will be calculated in the same manner - i.e. expression will be applied to total values in the same row.  I hope, this information will be helpful to you.

Comment: Well, that didn't quite do it, but it did lead me to the solution that works for me.  In the Fields Editor, I found the "UnboundExpression" property which I set to Iif([fieldSales]=0, 0 , [fieldProfitAmount]/[fieldSales]) which works out perfectly.  Then the summaries all calculate properly.  I'm marking this answer as "The Answer" since it led me in the right direction.